# How we can diff log files by ignoring first two lines of the files?

Tags: unix

I need to diff two log files but ignore first two line (As it contains Date) and print the output which is not common

Answer (score 1):

To skip first two lines you can use `tail` like this

```
tail -n +3 file
```

You can then write a `diff` command like this:

```
diff < (tail -n +3 file1) < (tail -n +3 file2)
```

The `diff` command prints the difference between the two files.